# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through custom post types and the code makes the page completely white but when I view source I can see my error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)
```

Here is my code, I am not sure why this is breaking as it was copy and pasted from a tutorial, I have tried it in numerous different template files and I get the same error so the error is secluded to this hunk of code:

```
 <?
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'members_features', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<? if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<? while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><? the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <? the_content(); ?> 
    </div>
        <? wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<? else:  ?>
    <p><? _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<? endif; ?>
```

The query recieves 1 row of data when I dump it and the query works fine, just the PHP notice is breaking my site, can any one help?

Comment: If you would 1) remove that PHP tag spam-- the spurious opening and closing tags (and there are a lot of them), 2) indent properly and carefully, and 3) avoid that nightmarish, unreadable [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) you'd probably spot the error. As this is a syntax error, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Also, it's best to avoid using [PHP short tags ](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) -- ie, replace `<?` with `<?php `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't ending your `while` before doing your `else`:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'members_features', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<? if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<? while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><? the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <? the_content(); ?> 
    </div>
        <? wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php /** no endwhile! **/
<? else:  ?>
    <p><? _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<? endif; ?>
```

It's easier to see the issue without the HMTL:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'members_features', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content(); 
        wp_reset_postdata();
        else: 
            _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
    endif;
```

Comment: ahhhh thanks! I am not used to this form of syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is not Ended. Throw in an

```
<? endwhile; ?>
```

before the wp_reset_postdata.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `endwhile` loop statement

```
    <div class="entry-content">
        <? the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <? endwhile; ?>
```